# What are all the ways to disable focusing on HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to implement the feature I've observed from [this](http://www.thepinaysolobackpacker.com/bali-travel-guide-for-first-timers/) site, which is ***the inability to select/highlight text***.

## Browsers

### Google Chrome

#### **Javascript**

Yes, I have tried disabling all Javascript from the site, invalidating Wordpress' plugin and any other script.

#### **CSS**

I have tried manipulating CSS via DevTools Elements

1. I added the style `p:focus { background-color: 'somecolor' }` but on mouse click+drag, it still doesn't activate focusing. Focusing can be activated by activating `:focus` in `DevTools Elements' force element state`.
2. I tried overriding `user-select`'s value from `none` to `text`, and even disabling the `user-select` attribute entirely.

#### **HTML**

I tried to strip the elements' HTML attributes so they'd be simple `<p>...</p>` tags

### On Firefox

You can focus on mouse click+drag by enabling reader view!

## Question

Since I've tried disabling Javascript, and manipulated the CSS and HTML. I've ran out of areas to isolate. Does anybody know how the unfocusable/unselectable was implemented?

Comment: That protects nothing in any meaningful sense of the word, press F12 and copy whatever you like.  Are you sure this is worth the effort?

Comment: Looks like they are using this Wordpress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protection/ You can check its source code

Comment: in the case of that site the body element has a class "unselectable" which is defined as follows: `.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: default
}` That seems to be how they're doing it, although possibly there's some script involved as well. It's still an experimental feature according to MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select . As others have mentioned, if anyone really wants to copy the content they can do it easily by looking at the source. Mostly this is just a really great way to annoy your users.

Comment: What an idiotic, unusable, effed-up site. This is not stopping anyone who actually wants to from copying the content, of course - but it decreases the usability _massively_.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, on Firefox reader view you can copy whatever you like. On developer tools you can copy whatever you like. For any web master any attempt to prevent copying content is futile. I merely became more interested because I've tried disabling it on normal view but I couldn't!

Comment: @yuriy636, Remember, I mentioned I tried disabling *ALL* Javascript via Chrome's feature. Also, I don't think that Wordpress plugin is open source, or I haven't looked hard enough!

Comment: still you can view source and select things from `view-source:http://www.thepinaysolobackpacker.com/bali-travel-guide-for-first-timers/`

Comment: @ADyson I disabled *ALL* Javascript features, and *stripped elements from all their attributes, classes included, essentially just leaving the elements and their contents. At this point I'm simply curious how it managed to stay unselectable despite me taking those measures.

Comment: @CBroe Yes. With regards to UX, this isn't really accessible and it is bad practice. I am just curious why after disabling Javascript and removing the style attribute, it stayed resistant.

Comment: @jpls93 The site uses a combination of the `.unselectable {user-select:none}` class, `html {user-select: none}` rules and the Wordpress plugin I mentioned before. If you remove all that, you can highlight the text without problem.

Comment: @Redo That's invalid since I've tried disabling Javascript as one of the tests.

Comment: @yuriy636 I've overriden the user-select attribute's value from `none` to `text` and disabled Wordpress' Plugin by disabling all Javascript from the site. I still can't highlight except on Firefox' reader view. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Seems like after disabling it on Chrome's DevTools Elements-Styles, it still was getting it from the plugin. I thought the plugin was a Javascript file so I isolated that one when I disabled javascript. I added an additional `p { user-select: text }` and it went through!

Comment: @jpls93 I got it to work. Rather than disabling JavaScript I went through and removed quite a few JavaScript events as well as the CSS. So it's definitely possible. Not sure why disabling script doesn't work, but there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) style. You can use it to disable selectable text. The support varies, but coverage is pretty good with `-webkit` etc. From w3schools:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: I've overriden the user-select attribute's value from `none` to `text` and disabled all Javascript from the site. I still can't highlight except on Firefox' reader view.

Comment: Seems like after disabling it on Chrome's DevTools Elements-Styles, it still was getting it from the plugin. I thought the plugin was a Javascript file so I isolated that one when I disabled javascript. I added an additional `p { user-select: text }` and it went through!

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you were just trying to default to unselectable. But that site seems to take it pretty far! I suppose you could implement various event listeners that just keep adding `user-select: none` to whatever elements, but like everyone keeps saying, it's all moot for anyone who can open devtools.